# Trying to upload image through an API and store it in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, go, multipartform-data

So I'm trying to upload image through an API and store it in a MySQL database. I'm unsure how to convert the `imageFile` to something that I can store in my DB.

I'm trying to store this image into a `blob` field on the `image` column of this table:

```
CREATE TABLE runkdb.uploaded_challenge (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    challenge_id int NOT NULL,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    image_caption TEXT,
    image_path varchar(255),
    image BLOB,
    score int DEFAULT 0,
    primary key (id)
);
```

This is part of the API function that tries to store the data:

```
// Parse the request
imageFile := make([]byte, 0)
image, _, err := req.FormFile("image")
if err != nil {
    // No image
    glog.Error("Error parsing image")
    responseMessage.Message = "Error parsing image"
    w.WriteHeader(400)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseMessage)
    return
} else {
    //if !strings.HasPrefix(fileHeader.Header["Content-Type"][0], "image") {
        // Something wrong with file type
    //}
    imageFile, err = ioutil.ReadAll(image)
    if err != nil {
        // Error reading uploaded image from stream
        glog.Error("Error reading image")
        responseMessage.Message = "Error reading image"
        w.WriteHeader(400)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseMessage)
        return
    }
}

imageCaption := req.Form.Get("image_caption")

// Create DB connection
txn, err := api.db.Begin()
if err != nil {
    glog.Error("Error creating database transaction")
    responseMessage.Message = "Error creating database transaction"
    w.WriteHeader(500)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseMessage)
    return
}

t := time.Now()
createdAtTimeString := fmt.Sprintf(t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
imageByteString := string(imageFile)
query := fmt.Sprintf("INSERT INTO uploaded_challenge (challenge_id, user_id, created_at, image_caption, image) VALUES ('%d', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s');", id, userID, createdAtTimeString, imageCaption, imageByteString)
print(query)
result, err := txn.Exec(query)
if err != nil {
    txn.Rollback()
    glog.Error("Error inserting challenge into database")
    responseMessage.Message = "Error inserting challenge into database"
    w.WriteHeader(406)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(responseMessage)
    return
}
```

Comment: Note that this is less popular than simply storing the image in a file server, and storing a path to the image in the database. Also, performance is likely to be disappointing for images above ca. 100k. Nonetheless, if you still want to do this then there are surely dozens of tutorials explaining how

Comment: I am aware of that and I still want to do this. I was trying to find a tutorial but couldn't for Golang.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by converting my `imageFile` to a string like this:

`encodedImage := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(imageFile)`

Then I stored the `encodedImage` into my database's `image` column (of type `BLOB`)